# Webpack Dev Server not rerendering after updating a module in nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-router-v4

I am getting the following error

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/Docs/bundle.c2e76650.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

It seems to work if the path is only one level deep (eg localhost/docs) with `react-router` but once a route is nested (eg localhost/docs/nestedRoute), it causes hot reloading to break.  Here is the relevant snapshot of my `webpack.config.js`.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: "dist",
    overlay: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
},
```

webpack -> `v4.1.1`

webpack-dev-server -> `v3.1.1`

Comment: Which versions of webpack, webpack-dev-server ?

Comment: `4.1.1` and `3.1.1` respectively, i solved the issue actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to my `webpack.config.js` fixed the issue...

```
{
...
  output: {
    ...
    publicPath: '/'
  }
}
```

Referenced [#978](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/978)